# react state is not updating from different calls

Tags: reactjs, properties, popup, setstate

In memory game project using react I'm trying to create pop-up at the end of the game with a button that lead you the next level (more cards).
to create the next level I'm using resetGame function which initial the state.
the property "isFinished" affect whether the popup will be shown or not.

if I press the Reset button - there is no problem.
if I press the next level button - all the properties in the state initialize except of isFinished and the popup remains.
as you can see, resetGame is called from the reset button and the FinishPopup component.

```
render() { 
        return ( 
            <div style={boardStyle}>
                <h1 style={titleStyle}>Memory Game</h1>
                <Timer reset={this.state.resetRequest} />
                <div>
                    <Button onClick={()=>this.resetGame(rowsVar,columnsVar)} type="button" className="btn btn-secondary">Reset</Button>
                </div>
                <div style={cardWrapper}>
                   {this.renderBoard()}
                   {this.checkIfGameOver()}
                   {this.state.isFinished ? (<FinishPopup nextLevel={()=>this.resetGame(rowsVar+1,columnsVar+1)} />) : null }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

this is the resetGame function:

```
resetGame=(rows,columns)=>{
    rowsVar=rows;
    columnsVar=columns;
    let newState = Object.assign({},this.state);
    newState.board = this.initialBoard(rows,columns);
    newState.numOfOpenCars = 0;
    newState.lastId="";
    newState.isFinished=false; //this is the property that does not changing
    newState.matchCounter=0;
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

and this is popup render function:

```
render() { 
    return ( 

    <div style={popupStyle}>
        <div>
            <h1>
                Well done!!
            </h1>
            <button onClick={this.props.nextLevel}>Next Level</button> 
        </div>
    </div>);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you setup a live example on CodeSandbox? That would help to better understand where the issue come from. https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: It's difficult to say what might be wrong without seeing all relevant code. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: it's not a big project yet, the relevant components are Board and FinishPopup.

https://codesandbox.io/s/5wrrq14yl

is it alright?